# Creating a column based on values of another column in a data frame

Tags: dataframe, dplyr

Considering the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame (Treatment = c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Med", "Med", "High", "High", "Med", "Low", "Med", "High", "High"), 
Value = c( 23,4,56,76,89,86,66,31,48,51,75,101))
```

| Treatment | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Low | 23 |
| Low | 4 |
| Low | 56 |
| Med | 76 |
| Med | 89 |
| High | 86 |
| High | 66 |
| Med | 31 |
| Low | 48 |
| Med | 51 |
| High | 75 |
| High | 101 |

and I would like to create a column so the data frame looks like:

| Treatment | Value | I.D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low | 23 | Low1 |
| Low | 4 | Low2 |
| Low | 56 | Low3 |
| Med | 76 | Med1 |
| Med | 89 | Med2 |
| High | 86 | High1 |
| High | 66 | High2 |
| Med | 31 | Med3 |
| Low | 48 | Low4 |
| Med | 51 | Med4 |
| High | 75 | High3 |
| High | 101 | High4 |

Basically I'd like to create a column with individual ID for each row based on the level they belong to.

I have tried this:

```
df %>% group_by (Treatment) %>%
          mutate (I.D = case_when(
                     Treatment == "Low" ~ paste ("Low",seq(1,4)),     
                     Treatment == "Med" ~ paste ("Med",seq(1,4)),
                     Treatment == "High" ~ paste("High",seq(1,4))))
```

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df |>
        group_by(Treatment) |> 
        mutate(id = paste0(Treatment, row_number()))
```

Output:

```
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   Treatment [3]
#>    Treatment Value id   
#>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 Low          23 Low1 
#>  2 Low           4 Low2 
#>  3 Low          56 Low3 
#>  4 Med          76 Med1 
#>  5 Med          89 Med2 
#>  6 High         86 High1
#>  7 High         66 High2
#>  8 Med          31 Med3 
#>  9 Low          48 Low4 
#> 10 Med          51 Med4 
#> 11 High         75 High3
#> 12 High        101 High4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>